# Edit row and col names in Pheatmap

Tags: r, pheatmap

I want to edit row and col names in my `pheatmap` or eventually delete and add new row and col names to be edited. In this case I will set `show_colnames` and `show_rownames` to  `FALSE`.

```
library("pheatmap")
pheatmap(scale(dat), show_colnames = T, show_rownames = T,legend = TRUE,
             cluster_rows=F, cluster_cols=F, border_color = "grey60")
```

Can somebody help me thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is the structure of a `pheatmap` object?

Comment: @AI14 : You lucked out and got an immediate response from someone who had a copy of whatever package this function resides in. But next time that you post a question about a function that is not in the "base" set of packages, you really ought to post a `library` or `require` call to load the mystery-package. You should NOT assume that we will know whether or not it is in a package of the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `labels_row` and `labels_col` parameters.

```
> set.seed(1)
> mat <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10, dimnames=list(letters[1:10], letters[11:20]))
> pheatmap(mat)
```

[image]

```
> pheatmap(mat, labels_row=paste0("foo", 1:10), labels_col=paste0("bar", 1:10))
```

[image]

Alternatively you can modify `rownames` / `colnames` of the matrix you pass to the `pheatmap` function.

```
library(magrittr)

mat %>%
    set_rownames(paste0("foo", 1:10)) %>%
    set_colnames(paste0("bar", 1:10)) %>%
    pheatmap()
```

Comment: HI I am trying to edit `set_rownames`  and `set_colnames` adding `plot(1, xaxt="n", yaxt="n"); axis(1, las=2); axis(2, las=1)` but it does not work. How can I rotate axis labels in a pheatmap?

Comment: Hi @zero323 would you know how to only show selected row label names based on their names (ie: foo1, foo6) ?